# How to calculate minimum , maximum, total and averge age from sashelp.class;

Tags: sas

Here I have sashelp.class.

In this we have 19 rows and 5 columns. I want to calculate the minimum, maximum, total and average age from the sashelp.class by using only data step.

Total rows: 19  - total columns: 5

```
1   Alfred  M   14  69  112.5   
2   Alice   F   13  56.5    84  
3   Barbara F   13  65.3    98  
4   Carol   F   14  62.8    102.5   
5   Henry   M   14  63.5    102.5   
6   James   M   12  57.3    83  
7   Jane    F   12  59.8    84.5    
8   Janet   F   15  62.5    112.5   
9   Jeffrey M   13  62.5    84  
10  John    M   12  59  99.5    
11  Joyce   F   11  51.3    50.5    
12  Judy    F   14  64.3    90  
13  Louise  F   12  56.3    77  
14  Mary    F   15  66.5    112 
15  Philip  M   16  72  150 
16  Robert  M   12  64.8    128 
17  Ronald  M   15  67  133 
18  Thomas  M   11  57.5    85  
19  William M   15  66.5    112 
 User: u63482558
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
data want;
   set sashelp.class end = z;

   if _N_ = 1 then minage = 999;

   if age < minage then minage = age;
   if age > maxage then maxage = age;

   sum + age;

   if z;
   avg = divide(sum, _N_);

   format avg 8.2;
   retain minage maxage;
run;
```

Comment: Recommended changes `set sashelp.class(keep=age where=(not missing(age)))` `want(drop=age)`